# Static discharge from HV ground wire

Tags: high-voltage, voltage-multiplier

I am building a small X-ray machine. The X-ray tube (БС-1) has a massive copper anode.

I am using a negative output HV multiplier driven by 10kV pulses from a HV transformer. The HV minus is connected to the tube cathode and the HV ground is connected to the anode.

During a test, I found that there was a big static discharge from the anode to anything, screwdriver, bolts, everything. I thought that the negative voltage was supposed to discharge from the HV minus.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

[image: HV assembly (]

[image: Multiplier chematic]

The HV assembly was covered in silicone under vacuum.

[image: xray tube copper anode body]

Answer (score 0):

The source which produces the AC input voltage obviously is floating. None of its output wires are connected the real local ground - I mean to the house items like the concrete and  the ground of the mains AC wiring. You may try to to make such connection. Insert a short wire from the tube Anode to the real local ground. If the AC input voltage is short sharp pulses only a short grounding cable will be useful. How short? Impossible to be sure without knowing the pulse forms.

It's well possible that the AC input voltage source gets trashed if it's not designed to stand grounding one of its outputs. Impossible to be sure without having a full schematic and detailed construction image of your AC source.

One solution (a crutch) is to place all items inside a grounded Faraday cage, but as insulated.

Comment: Yea, but I am trying to make my xray machine portable, finding connection to ground maybe very difficult in some places. I am thinking of covering the whole anode in varnish to prevent discharge.

Comment: Will be not useful. There's sooner or later a crack, probably from the start. Transformer oil could work. But you can carry your own ground - 1...2 square meter  piece of metal mesh, maybe originally intended to be fence material. It surely makes enough contact to a concrete floor, too. I'm afraid radio communication may suffer of your pulses. Check it before a cry.

Comment: @confusedtick606 (continued) X-ray generators with any useful power are heavily constrained by the law where I live. This article tells something of the era when X-rays were not known by the law.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray Where are they allowed as hobby projects? And what useful the rays your machine makes actually do? I am just curious.

Comment: I live in Russia, there are a lot of x-ray "builders", even the famous "sifun" incident, where teenager was exposed to large doses by homemade machine. There are definitely laws that require some kind of license, but it is not enforced. I am trying to make an x ray microscope (inspired by youtu.be/S5KlqaATiIo?si=VoYLzaRXtpQnl586).

Comment: About the transformer. It is driven by 5kHz pulses from MOSFET connected to arduino.

Comment: Ceaușescu, the dictator of Romania used an X-ray machine in a creative way. He used one to give a little slow, but effective (say 2 Sv) lessons to persons who were either suspected opponents or minions, only fallen out of favor. I'm sure his colleaques still use the same method because it's clean. No bullet wounds, no trained specialists which handle the case with polonium, novitshok, car accident, slipping at the edge of a roof etc... Only call the person to visit and let him sit a while on a comfortable chair. A group or a family can be treated all in once in a well equipped waiting room.